# How to move a li item from one list to another on a double click?

Tags: jquery, listview

Here i am using two listview controls List1 and List2 and on double click of a li item in List1 it
is moving to List2 but when i double click that same item in List2 it is not moving to List1
here is my code

```
$("#list1 li").dblclick(function () {
$("#list1 li.clicked").removeClass("clicked").appendTo('#list2');
});

$("#list2 li").dblclick(function () {
$("#list2 li.clicked").removeClass("clicked").appendTo('#list1');
});
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delegation, which compares clicked elements against a selector at the time the click was fired (i.e. up-to-date as to which list the element is in).

Prior to jQuery 1.7, this was done using [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate), but as of 1.7 you should be using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on).

When you were binding to the element directly, this only takes into account the state of the element at the time the handler was bound, not the current state.

```
$("#list1").on('dblclick', 'li', function () {
    $("#list1 li.clicked").removeClass("clicked").appendTo('#list2');
});

$("#list2").on('dblclick', 'li', function () {
    $("#list2 li.clicked").removeClass("clicked").appendTo('#list1');
});
```

Additionally, are you sure you don't want to be using `this` inside the event handler, rather than `#list1 li.clicked` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I think it is because when you move the element, it loses it's binding. If you use `.on('event',fuynction(){ ... })` (or `.live` in older jQueries) it should keep the binding.

```
$("#list1 li").on('dblclick',function () {
$("#list1 li.clicked").removeClass("clicked").appendTo('#list2');
});

$("#list2 li").on('dblclick',function () {
$("#list2 li.clicked").removeClass("clicked").appendTo('#list1');
});
```

Comment: `on()` is not the same as `live()` when used like that; `$(document).on('dblclick', '#list1 li', function () {})` would be however. The event binding is also not lost; it's bound to the element, so when you move the element around, the handler remains attached.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the events on the list items, which means that the item that you moved to the second list still has the same event handler as when it was in the first list. Double clicking an item that has been moved once will move it to the list where it is already, so it appears as nothing is happening.

Use the [`delegate` method](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to bind the events to the lists intead of the list items:

```
$("#list1").delegate("li", "dblclick", function () {
  $("#list1 li.clicked").removeClass("clicked").appendTo('#list2');
});

$("#list2").delegate("li", "dblclick", function () {
  $("#list2 li.clicked").removeClass("clicked").appendTo('#list1');
});
```

Alternatively, you can let the event handler figure out which list the list item is in. That way the event handler works wherever the list item is, and you can use the same event handler for both lists:

```
$("#list1 li, #list2 li").dblclick(function () {
  var source = $(this).closest('ul');
  var target = source.attr('id') == "list1" ? $("#list2") : $("#list1");
  $("li.clicked", source).removeClass("clicked").appendTo(target);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are binding the event to the list item itself. moving it away from it's container, you lose it's effect.

[here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/WKmBk/) using `.on()`. this way, you bind the handler to the parent, and any child, whether existing or soon to be placed will be affected. i stripped the removeclass, you may add it back

```
$(function() {

    //any "li", existing or soon to be, that is "double-clicked" in "list1", move to list2

    $("#list1").on('dblclick','li',function() {
        $(this).appendTo('#list2');
    });

    //any "li", existing or soon to be,  that is "double-clicked" in "list2", move to list1

    $("#list2").on('dblclick','li',function() {
        $(this).appendTo('#list1');
    });

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#list1").on('dblclick', 'li', function () {
    $(this).remove().appendTo('#list2');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#list1 li").dblclick(function () {
            $("#list1 li.clicked").removeClass("clicked").appendTo('#list2');
            $("#list2 li.clicked").removeClass("clicked").appendTo('#list1');
            });

        $("#list4 li").dblclick(function () {
            $("#list2 li.clicked").removeClass("clicked").appendTo('#list1');
            $("#list1 li.clicked").removeClass("clicked").appendTo('#list2');
            });
```